# Matlab, how to calculate AUC (Area Under Curve)?

Tags: matlab, octave, area, curve

I have the file `data.txt` with two columns and N rows, something like this:

```
0.009943796 0.4667975
0.009795735 0.46777886
0.009623984 0.46897832
0.009564759 0.46941447
0.009546991 0.4703958
0.009428543 0.47224948
0.009375241 0.47475737
0.009298249 0.4767201
[...]
```

Every couple of values in the file correspond to one point coordinates (x,y).
If plotted, this points generate a curve. I would like to calculate the area under curve (AUC) of this curve.

So I load the data:

```
data = load("data.txt");
X = data(:,1);
Y = data(:,2);
```

So, `X` contains all the x coordinates of the points, and `Y` all the y coordinates.

How could I calculate the area under curve (AUC) ?

Comment: It depends.  Is the [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezium_rule) good enough for you?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24597-area-under-a-curve

Comment: @Robert: that looks like it's the area under the curve of a *function* (Matlab has a whole bunch of `quad`xxxx() functions). OP is looking for numerical integration of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is the trapezoidal rule function [`trapz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/trapz.html).

If your data is known to be smooth, you could try using Simpson's rule, but there's nothing built-in to MATLAB for integrating numerical data via Simpson's rule. (& I'm not sure how to use it for x/y data where x doesn't increase steadily)

Comment: Thanx guys, I have tried with trapz(), but it strangely gives me always negative values. Why this? If it is an area, it should be always positive... Any idea? Thanx!

Comment: If the curve go below 0 the area actually will be decreased. This is just integral, remember. To get the positive AUC you might need to change the baseline. For example, subtract the `min(Y)` from `Y`. Or you can use `abs(Y)` to sum up positive and negative areas.

Comment: Technically, if you use `trapz(x,y)`, the sign of the result depends on the sign of y and the sign of the change in x. (remember: this is integral of y dx) So if your y values are positive but x is decreasing, you'd get a negative number. It's actually a little more complicated than that: for closed curves, the sign should be positive for clockwise encircling and negative for counterclockwise encircling (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_Calculation ).

Answer (score 4):

just add
AUC = trapz(X,Y)
to your program
and you will get the area under the curve

Answer (score 2):

[~,~,~,AUC] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass);

% posclass might be 1

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/252131

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
AUC = sum((Y(1:end-1)+Y(2:end))/2.*...
  (X(2:end)-X(1:end-1)));
```

Comment: Oli, could you pls add an explanation or link for the equation you used?

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Link](http://cnx.org/content/m41454/latest/)

An example in MATLAB to help you get your answer ...

```
x=[3 10 15 20 25 30];
y=[27 14.5 9.4 6.7 5.3 4.5];
trapz(x,y)
```

In case you have negative values in **y**, you can do like,

```
y=max(y,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to `trapz` for the person ready to do some coding by themselves. This link shows the implementation of [Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule), with python code included. There is also a [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28726-simpson-s-rule-integration/content/simpsons.m) on simpsons rule.